# DDL for SQL Membership/Roles Provider

Tags: .net, sql, roles

Where can I get the DDL to add SQL Roles and Membership to an existing SQL Server database? I want to use the providers but I'd like to manually run the scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find the sql files in:
[SystemDrive]\Microsoft.Net\Framework\[version]

For example the Files might be located in:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Look for the .sql files they are all easy to spot.

---

Remember that 3.0 and 3.5 of the .Net Framework are built on 2.0 so all the SQL files are in the .NET 2.0 directory.